# How to add html color picker using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to add a HTML color-picker using JQuery.

Is there an easier way to achieve this without adding any JQuery libraries?

Tried `<input type="color">` but it's not working.

Comment: Please provide the not working code, maybe we can fix it instead of making assumptions :)

Just so you know, `<input type="color" />` is HTML5, be sure that your site works on HTML5 ;)

Comment: might be a browser compatibility issue..please re-verify that

Comment: If you google for "jquery color picker" you will find some jQuery plugins and if you look at the code you will want to use them instead of writing your own.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will serve you.
I have not tried it, so I hope you tell me if it serves you.
Greetings.

Basic with Spectrum

```
    $(".basic").spectrum({
color: "#f00",
change: function(color) {
    $("#basic-log").text("change called: " + color.toHexString());
}});
```

Full with Spectrum

```
$("#full").spectrum({
color: "#ECC",
showInput: true,
className: "full-spectrum",
showInitial: true,
showPalette: true,
showSelectionPalette: true,
maxSelectionSize: 10,
preferredFormat: "hex",
localStorageKey: "spectrum.demo",
move: function (color) {

},
show: function () {

},
beforeShow: function () {

},
hide: function () {

},
change: function() {

},
palette: [
    ["rgb(0, 0, 0)", "rgb(67, 67, 67)", "rgb(102, 102, 102)",
    "rgb(204, 204, 204)", "rgb(217, 217, 217)","rgb(255, 255, 255)"],
    ["rgb(152, 0, 0)", "rgb(255, 0, 0)", "rgb(255, 153, 0)", "rgb(255, 255, 0)", "rgb(0, 255, 0)",
    "rgb(0, 255, 255)", "rgb(74, 134, 232)", "rgb(0, 0, 255)", "rgb(153, 0, 255)", "rgb(255, 0, 255)"], 
    ["rgb(230, 184, 175)", "rgb(244, 204, 204)", "rgb(252, 229, 205)", "rgb(255, 242, 204)", "rgb(217, 234, 211)", 
    "rgb(208, 224, 227)", "rgb(201, 218, 248)", "rgb(207, 226, 243)", "rgb(217, 210, 233)", "rgb(234, 209, 220)", 
    "rgb(221, 126, 107)", "rgb(234, 153, 153)", "rgb(249, 203, 156)", "rgb(255, 229, 153)", "rgb(182, 215, 168)", 
    "rgb(162, 196, 201)", "rgb(164, 194, 244)", "rgb(159, 197, 232)", "rgb(180, 167, 214)", "rgb(213, 166, 189)", 
    "rgb(204, 65, 37)", "rgb(224, 102, 102)", "rgb(246, 178, 107)", "rgb(255, 217, 102)", "rgb(147, 196, 125)", 
    "rgb(118, 165, 175)", "rgb(109, 158, 235)", "rgb(111, 168, 220)", "rgb(142, 124, 195)", "rgb(194, 123, 160)",
    "rgb(166, 28, 0)", "rgb(204, 0, 0)", "rgb(230, 145, 56)", "rgb(241, 194, 50)", "rgb(106, 168, 79)",
    "rgb(69, 129, 142)", "rgb(60, 120, 216)", "rgb(61, 133, 198)", "rgb(103, 78, 167)", "rgb(166, 77, 121)",
    "rgb(91, 15, 0)", "rgb(102, 0, 0)", "rgb(120, 63, 4)", "rgb(127, 96, 0)", "rgb(39, 78, 19)", 
    "rgb(12, 52, 61)", "rgb(28, 69, 135)", "rgb(7, 55, 99)", "rgb(32, 18, 77)", "rgb(76, 17, 48)"]
]});
```

[JQuery Plugin :: Spectrum](https://plugins.jquery.com/spectrum/)
[Spectrum Complete Example :: JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bgrins/ctkY3/)

--
Apkahym

Answer (score 0):

I think it can help you [see here](https://codepen.io/thamtucity/pen/MrbXKb)

**html**

```
<p>Text with stroke</p>
<input type="color" value="#ff0000">
```

**css**

```
p {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 4em;
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 3px;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: #ff0000; 
}
```

**jquery**

```
var colorPicker = document.querySelector("input");
colorPicker.addEventListener("change", function(evt) {
  document.querySelector("p").style.webkitTextStrokeColor = evt.target.value;
});
```